NestJS TypeORM generic inheritance of Repository not working
I am trying to create a custom repository class that extends Repository.
Here is the code
user.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { User } from 'src/domain/composite/user/user';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/infrastructure/repositories/user/user.repository';
import { UserMapper } from 'src/infrastructure/mappers/user/user.mapper';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserRepository)
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    const users = await this.userRepository.findAll();
    return users.map((user) => UserMapper.toDomain(user));
  }
}

user.repository.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { BaseAbstractRepostitory } from '../common/baseAbstract.repository';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/domain/entities/user/user.entity';
import { Repository, EntityRepository} from "typeorm";
import { BaseInterfaceRepository } from '../common/baseInterface.repository';


@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends BaseAbstractRepostitory<UserEntity> implements BaseInterfaceRepository<UserEntity> {
    constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>) {
        super(userRepository);
      } 
}

base.repository.ts
import {
  DeepPartial,
  FindManyOptions,
  FindOneOptions,
  FindOperator,
  Repository,
  UpdateResult,
  Equal,
} from 'typeorm';

import { BaseInterfaceRepository } from './baseInterface.repository';

interface HasId {
  id: string;
  deleted: boolean;
}

export abstract class BaseAbstractRepostitory<T extends HasId>
  implements BaseInterfaceRepository<T>
{
  private entity: Repository<T>;
  protected constructor(entity: Repository<T>) {
    this.entity = entity;
  }
  public async findAll(
    options?: FindManyOptions<T>,
    deleted: boolean = false,
  ): Promise<T[]> {
    if (!options) {
      options = {};
    }

    // Ensure options.where is defined
    options.where = options.where || {};

    // Update options.where with the 'deleted' flag
    options.where = {
      ...(options.where as any), // Cast options.where to 'any'
      deleted: deleted,
    };

    return this.entity.find(options);
  }
}

domain.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from 'src/infrastructure/repositories/user/user.repository';
import { UserService } from './service/user/user.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository])],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService, TypeOrmModule],
})
export class DomainModule {}

application.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserController } from './controller/user/user.controller';
import { UserService } from 'src/domain/service/user/user.service';
import { DomainModule } from '../domain/domain.module';

@Module({
  imports: [DomainModule],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}

This is the folder structure:

so the output of the function when I call the API is:
[Nest] 39455  - 04/02/2024, 2:56:41 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] this.userRepository.findAll is not a function

Also, I followed this guide to create the generic repository
Enhancing Code Reusability with NestJS Abstract Repository Pattern Best Practices and Examples
I read typeorm documentation about custom repositories: https://typeorm.io/custom-repository#how-to-create-custom-repository
StackOverflow:

NestJS typeorm generic inheritance of Repository not working, this.function is not a function

Github: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2097
Yet nothing is working, is there something wrong with the following code ?
